# Pushing docker image to gitlab fails: unauthorized

Tags: docker, gitlab

I'm trying to push an image to my gitlab registry which i previously built with success.

```
docker login registry.gitlab.com
```

I give the credentials and it returns me a "Login Succeeded"

Then, as always, i do a

```
docker push registry.gitlab.com/username/registry/base:latest
```

And it ends with

```
unauthorized: authentication required
```

i already tried to

```
docker logout registry.gitlab.com
```

and login again.

The process can be found here, it's pretty simple

[link to github/gitlabhq](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/user/packages/container_registry/index.md#authenticate-with-the-container-registry)

I'm used to do it like that, first time i face the issue, don't understand

Any help appreciated !

Comment: It sounds like you may not be logged in to your GitLab account correctly. Try logging out and then logging back in again to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Thank for reply. I already did it, re-logged in with succes, and again unauthorized

Comment: very interesting, that is all what I know about.. will leave it to the others support.

Comment: is it possible you need extra authorization in gitlab that you do not currently have?

Comment: I'm used to build and push my images to my gitlab namespace this way. The commands i use are from the gitlab CLI help. I'v never seen any extra credentialsor step  needed anywhere in the docs

Comment: your not passing any credentials to login to the continer registry with see https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/user/packages/container_registry/index.md#authenticate-by-using-gitlab-cicd

Comment: `docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY`

Comment: When i do docker login to the registry, then i'm asked to give username and password, and it returns me a success login

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your account has read/write access to the registry you are trying to access. What you might need to do is to create a new Access Token as there is a difference between API/Access tokens and your "normal" user password. Use this access token as described in the documentation (https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/user/packages/container_registry/index.md#authenticate-with-the-container-registry)

```
docker login registry.example.com -u <username> -p <token>
```

The token can be created by going to **Edit Profile -> Access Tokens -> Select Scopes -> Ticking off 'Read registry' & 'Write registry'**

Comment: Thank you for this reply. I just ended a ticket with the support and it appears it is due to a native limitation of the token duration.

Answer (score 0):

The Gitlab support told me this is due to a native limitation of the token duration.
You cannot customize this duration in Saas mode.
So pushing large image results in auto logout.

Answer (score 0):

Check the limit of users in the GitLab settings;

The error occurred to me because my user was in a read-only state due to the limit of users for the free plan.